# How to share Mac screen to Linux docker container?

Tags: linux, macos, docker, x11, vnc

I want to run odesk time tracker (a Qt4 app) which captures your screen and keystrokes for freelance work logging. But I don't trust it and want to sandbox it.

On Linux, there are ways to run GUI items on docker container and forward  X11 to Linux host. Can I do this on mac? The app will run on Linux container and will be displayed on Mac with capturing screen/keystroke.

I think VNC method would display the linux host, not the mac. If linux connects mac, I have to install the software on mac. I don't know if I can do X11 forwarding.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have XQuartz installed on your Mac. You can get it here -

http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

Once you installed it, follow this procedure -

1. Run X11 application (included with XQuartz)
2. Open X11 Preferences and make sure "Allow connections..." is checked
   [image: X11 Preferences]
3. Restart X11 application
4. Open a terminal
5. ssh to your docker with X11 forwarding: `ssh -X YOUR_DOCKER_IP`

From now on, any GUI application that you run on your docker will show up on your Mac.

Comment: This isn't actually applicable here. X11 applications will *display* on the Mac, but this specific application requires considerably more access than X11 would give it.

Comment: I am not familiar with specifics of odesk application. I use this procedure to forward X11 applications from my work computer (Linux) to my home Mac. I thought it would be useful to the OP.